# What regular expression will match decimal values restricted to 6 decimal positions?

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write a regular expression that will match the following patterns, it should match decimal values, which can be in the formats shown below.

> 1. +100.00
> 2. -100.00
> 3. .6777
> 4. 0.45555
> 5. the normal entry of the decimal values like 100 100.25 100....
>      and also the decimal points should be restricted 6 decimal positions.

This is the regular expression I have written so far:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(value, "^((\\+|-)(\\d*))+((\\.|,)\\d{0,5})?$");
```

Currently if the value is like `+100` or `-100` the reqular expression matches. If I enter a value like `100`, it is not accepted and if I start with the a decimal point like `.899` then `IsMatch` returns false.

Comment: Look to make your first group optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct expression is

```
^((\+|-)?(\d*))+((\.|,)\d{0,6})?$
```

You can test it at http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm.

Comment: dictus : i am using this expression to vaildate on the key entry, when enter = the expression returns true. how to avoid this

Comment: @khachik: True, I hadn't noticed the extra parens. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with:

```
^[+-]?\d*([.,]\d{1,6})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

`(+|-)?\d*[.,]?\d{0,6}$` and 7 gnomes to be posted.

Comment: @hsz: "the normal entry of the decimal values like...". `123` is normal decimal value, I think.

Comment: `@khachik` sure but it allows a dot after normal decimal value and no digits after.

Comment: @hsz: sorry, I meant `123.` is a normal decimal value.